# How to keep CSS counter consistant across tables?

Tags: css, css-counter

My HTML document is formatted to have its content printed.  Each printed page is framed inside a table.

The document also has headings laid out on the pages (h1...h5).

The problem is when a a sub-heading (at level h2..h5) is continued on the next printed page (i.e.: table).

This is what I get:

```
1.     (1.)
1.1.   (1.1.)
1.2.   (1.2.)
1.2.1. (1.2.1.)
1.3.   (1.3.)
---------------- page break (i.e.: new table)
1.1.   (1.4.)
2.     (2.)
2.1.   (2.1.)
2.1.1. (2.1.1)
2.1.2. (2.1.2)
```

As you can see, the H2 element is out in the weeds when referenced in the next table.  Specifically, it is "1.1" when I want it to be "1.4".

Here's my html/css:

```html
    <HTML>
     <HEAD>
      <STYLE>
       .initHeadingCounters
        {
        counter-reset: headingCounter1 headingCounter2 headingCounter3 headingCounter4 headingCounter5;
        }

       .counter_h1
        {
        counter-reset: headingCounter2 headingCounter3 headingCounter4 headingCounter5;
        }
       .counter_h1:before
        {
        counter-increment: headingCounter1;
        content: counter(headingCounter1) ". ";
        }

       .counter_h2
        {
        counter-reset: headingCounter3 headingCounter4 headingCounter5;
        }
       .counter_h2:before
        {
        counter-increment: headingCounter2;
        content: counter(headingCounter1) "." counter(headingCounter2) ". ";
        }

       .counter_h3
        {
        counter-reset: headingCounter4 headingCounter5;
        }
       .counter_h3:before
        {
        counter-increment: headingCounter3;
        content: counter(headingCounter1) "." counter(headingCounter2) "." counter(headingCounter3) ". ";
        }

       .counter_h4
        {
        counter-reset: headingCounter5;
        }
       .counter_h4:before
        {
        counter-increment: headingCounter4;
        content: counter(headingCounter1) "." counter(headingCounter2) "." counter(headingCounter3) "." counter(headingCounter4) ". ";
        }
      </STYLE>
     </HEAD>

     <BODY>
      <DIV Class="initHeadingCounters">

      <TABLE>
       <TR>
        <TD>
         <H1 Class="counter_h1">(1)</H1>
          <H2 Class="counter_h2">(1.1)</H2>
           <H2 Class="counter_h2">(1.2)</H2>
           <H3 Class="counter_h3">(1.2.1)</H3>
          <H2 Class="counter_h2">(1.3)</H2>
        </TD>
       </TR>
      </TABLE>

      <TABLE>
       <TR>
        <TD>
          <H2 Class="counter_h2">(1.4)</H2>
         <H1 Class="counter_h1">(2)</H1>
          <H2 Class="counter_h2">(2.1)</H2>
           <H3 Class="counter_h3">(2.1.1)</H3>
           <H3 Class="counter_h3">(2.1.2)</H3>
        </TD>
       </TR>
      </TABLE>

     </DIV>
    </BODY>
   </HTML>
```

Comment: This is interesting, not sure if you can avoid it. It's explained in item 12.4.1 Nested counters and scope https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counters

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto, Thanks... You may be right; that it can't be avoided.  Just hoping for a css miracle worker who might...

Comment: Interesting problem. I had hopes that you could avoid the inner nested `counter-reset` properties, by writing something like `counter-increment: headingCounter3 -counter(headingCounter3)` instead, or some variant with `calc`, but none of that works. Sorry!

Comment: @MrLister, I went down that same calc road as you did, with the same lack of  success. Thanks for your pursuit.